# iOS Complex sectionNameKeyPath issue

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to create a NSFetchedResultsController using date and type.

My Data looks like this :

```
{
 @"date", NSDate,
 @"type", NSString
}
```

This is what my NSManagedObject

```
- (NSString*)dayTypeStringOnly {

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i%i%@", (int)[[cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self.startTime] year],(int)[[cal components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:self.startTime] month],(int)[[cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:self.date] day], [self.type lowercaseString]];
}
```

Here is my NSFetchedResultsController:

```
NSFetchRequest *dataRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
[dataRequest setPredicate:kHiddenPredicate];
[dataRequest setFetchBatchSize:kMagicalRecordDefaultBatchSize];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type" ascending:NO selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[dataRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES], sortDescriptor]];
NSFetchedResultsController *dataFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:dataRequest
                                                                                               managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]
                                                                                                 sectionNameKeyPath:@"dayTypeStringOnly"
                                                                                                          cacheName:nil];
```

I am getting this error:

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x10e847230 {reason=The fetched object at index 8 has an out of order section name '20131011pump. Objects must be sorted by section name'}, {
    reason = "The fetched object at index 8 has an out of order section name '20131011pump. Objects must be sorted by section name'";
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hint: the `dayTypeStringOnly` needs to go first in the sort descriptors, then add your other sort descriptors after.

Comment: I think the problem is that `dayTypeStringOnly`, his only attributes are `@"date"` and `@"type"`

Comment: @Kevin He has a custom getter called `dayTypeStringOnly` in the `NSManagedObject` subclass.  This is standard for creating derived properties from actual model properties like he is doing.

Comment: I was under the impression that you couldn't use derived properties to sort (I asked a question which led me to believe this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558421/nspredicate-in-nsfetchedresultscontroller-doesnt-use-categorys-getter

Comment: I stand corrected then

Comment: I can't put dayTypeStringOnly into the sort descriptor: 'keypath dayTypeStringOnly not found in entity'

Comment: @iWasRobbed: You can use transient/derived properties as `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter, but *not* in a (SQLite based) Core Data sort descriptor.

Comment: @TimWalsh: The problem is indeed that you have to add a first sort descriptor that is "compatible" with your `sectionNameKeyPath`. If that were just "year-month-day" than you could use the "date" attribute as first sort descriptor, but with "year-month-day-type" you are probably out of luck. You may have to add "dayTypeStringOnly" as an additional *persistent* attribute of your entity.

Comment: @Marin you are correct, it works fine when you just a date, but once I add in the type...it fails.  Looks like having another field with that data would be a clean solution.  If you want to repost your answer, I will happily accept it.

Comment: The question has already been closed as a duplicate, therefore I cannot post an answer anymore.